# How to plot the reflection coefficent at the load against frequency in ADS

Tags: load, reflection, ads

The reflection coefficeint at the load is defined as

[image]

how do I plot the load reflection coefficent against frequency in ADS?
it is easy to plot the source reflection coefficient since it is just defined as S11, but I have issue ploting the load refflection coefficient

[image]

Comment: Just get rid of TL1, and attach TermG1 where you want to measure the reflection.

Comment: how about Z0? the characterisitc impedance of the line. Can it just be replace by the resistance in the TermG1?